# Assets Module only grants Super Admin access

Tags: assets, admin

Assets v2.1.4
ExpressionEngine v2.5.5

I'm experiencing issues when trying to access the assets module when logged in as any user other than Super Admin. The other member group's privileges and preferences have all been set to yes so they are allowed access to the module. However, accessing Assets from Modules or an entry, none of the images are displayed. When logged in as a Super Admin, these images are available. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Update to at least Assets 2.2 and EE 2.7.2 for a fix.